# In output from `apt update` what do 'InRelease' and 'Release' refer to?

Tags: debian, apt

Here is an example showing the '**InRelease**' and '**Release**' line suffixes:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:4 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                        
Ign:6 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                         
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release               
Hit:8 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease           
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release                
...
```

I know what a Release is.  Although a web search for InRelease didn't turn up much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`InRelease` files are equivalent to `Release` files with the exception that they contain an inline GPG signature, whereas validating `Release` files requires downloading a separate `Release.gpg` file. Having the signature in line avoids race conditions when downloading.

[This FTP master meeting summary](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2009/11/msg00001.html) contains this feature’s announcement, with a brief description.

Since the title asks about them too, I’ll mention that [`Release` files](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#A.22Release.22_files) contain distribution metadata and the checksums of the index files.

Answer (score 7):

Another reference to this is here:

> InRelease files are signed in-line while Release files should have an
>   accompanying Release.gpg file.

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Origin