# apt - Skipping acquisition of `i386` packages

Tags: debian, apt

I'm on Debian Bullseye XFCE.  Please find the relevant details of my system below:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ uname -a
Linux krishna 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `sources.list` has the following lines which makes DVD-1 of the Debian ISO as a local repostory.

```bsh
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/debian-dvd-1/ bullseye non-free contrib main
```

I need to run the following commands in the terminal:

```bsh
mount ~/firmware-11.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso /media/debian-dvd-1/
sudo apt update
```

I get the following output:

```bsh
Get:1 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease
Ign:1 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease
Get:2 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release [20.9 kB]
Get:2 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release [20.9 kB]
Get:3 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release.gpg
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                          
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                  
Fetched 2,461 B in 2s (996 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
13 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

What do the lines

```bsh
Get:1 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease
Ign:1 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease
Get:2 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release [20.9 kB]
Get:2 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release [20.9 kB]
Get:3 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye Release.gpg
```

and

```bsh
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'file:/media/debian-dvd-1 bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

mean? Is this of any concern? If yes, what should be the rectification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first few lines tell you what files `apt` tried to retrieve, and which one it found (`Release`). See [In output from `apt update` what do 'InRelease' and 'Release' refer to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498033/86440) for details of what these files are.

The last few lines are notices informing you that some of your system’s configured architectures (`i386`, which is presumably set up as a foreign architecture) couldn’t be found in your “mirror” (the CD image).

All of this is normal and nothing to worry about. You can avoid the second set of output by describing your repository more specifically:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 trusted=yes ] file:///media/debian-dvd-1/ bullseye non-free contrib main
```

This will tell `apt` to only look for `amd64` content in that repository.

Comment: How can I get rid of i386 packages completely from my system? I mean even for the online repositories? They aren't useful on an amd64 system, isn't it? I use `wine` with i386. But I want to get rid of other packages that download i386 packages when I update my system.

Comment: If you use `i386` Wine then you need all its `i386` dependencies, and you need the `i386` metadata from the repositories.